# Why can I create arrays larger than the allocated buffer to jupyter?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, jupyter-notebook

This is what my `jupyter_notebook_config.py` looks like:

```
## Gets or sets the maximum amount of memory, in bytes, that is allocated for use
#  by the buffer manager.
#  Default: 536870912
# c.NotebookApp.max_buffer_size = 536870912
```

So, I can see that the max buffer allocated to my jupyter is about 0.5GB. (536870912/(1024**3) == 0.5)

Yet, I can create numpy array that occupy about 2 GBs of my RAM using the following code

```
import numpy as np
ra = np.random.rand(16384,16384).astype('float64')
16384*16384*64/(8*(1024**3)) == 2
ra.nbytes/(1024**3) == 2.0
```

And, my htop command verifies that 2 GBs of memory actually got used

Am I missing what max_buffer_size means? Why can I use 2 GBs from my RAM when the jupyter is configured to use only 0.5 GBs?